# Export a .NET WinForms Form to PDF?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, richtextbox

I have a .NET WinForms containing a few user controls. these controls usually contain either a RichTextBox or similar text controls (also 3rd party grid, XtraGrid suite, but those have the feature i want). I want to export the form the same way it looks to a PDF document.

I've seen several libraries and general PDF creation features but im completely confused as to what i need exactly.

If anyone has any suggestions how to do the scenario I'm talking about, I'd appreciate the help and personal experience with PDF.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but one simple possibility would be to use the [PrintForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/aa701261.aspx) component in combination with one of the many programs that allow you to print to a pdf document instead of a printer.

Example apps that let you print to PDF include the full blown Adobe suite, [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/) (free)

Comment: +1 - PrintForm does exactly what it says on the tin. It'll also allow the user to print to the printer if they want to as well.

Comment: Sadly, It's not the type of solution i was looking for. The PDF generation needs to be automatic/programmatic since im creating a PDF from my data and sending it to a different system/location.